# How can I convert Next Js app to pwa in Nx?

Tags: next.js, progressive-web-apps, nx-monorepo

I have developed a next app in the nx monopo and I need convert it to pwa app.
I try to install next-pwa package  but I dont know how should I change the next config file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think there is any difference between using a monorepo or multirepo for Next.js. You just need to update the `next.config.js` as desired.

Once the `next-pwa` package is installed, open your `next.config.js` file and update it as follows ([source](https://github.com/shadowwalker/next-pwa#configuration)):

```
const withNx = require("@nrwl/next/plugins/withNx");
const withPWA = require("next-pwa");

module.exports = withNx(
  withPWA({
    pwa: {
      dest: "public",
      register: true,
      skipWaiting: true,
    },
    // Other Next.js configuration options
  })
);
```

This configuration sets the destination directory for the PWA files to the public folder, enables the service worker registration, and skips waiting for the service worker to activate.

Comment: Thank you Amir Hossein, but next has a special plugin that it is @Nx/next. This package return a function that it is withNx. It cause the next app files to build based on the project.json file. So it seems we need combine the withNx with withPwa plugin

Comment: @miladshiriyan please checkout the update and tell me.